# How can I add space between bars in a dodged (hue) group?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, grouped-bar-chart, seaborn-0.12.x

How can I add space between Male and Female bars in seaborn histplot ?

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
sns.histplot(data=tips, x="day", hue="sex", multiple="dodge", shrink=.9)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Technically, this is a countplot (barplot) implemented with `sns.histplot`. A histogram shows the distribution of continuous data. More simply `ax = sns.countplot(data=tips, x='day', hue='sex')`

Comment: See [how to get spacing between grouped bar plot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66913686/7758804), [Bar graph spacing between grouped bars](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63378978/7758804), [How to increase the bar width in a grouped bar plot without reducing the gap between groups](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61183826/7758804)

Comment: `ax = sns.histplot(data=tips, x="day", hue="sex", multiple="dodge", shrink=.9, ec='w', lw=2)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I don't think this can be achieved directly with `sns.histplot`, you could use the [seaborn.objects](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/objects_interface.html) interface, which is more flexible (at the expense of complexity).

For this specific example, here's how you could achieve the same plot, but with a gap between the bars (see [seaborn.objects.Dodge](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.objects.Dodge.html)):

```py
import seaborn as sns
import seaborn.objects as so
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
so.Plot(tips, x="day", color="sex").add(so.Bar(), so.Count(), so.Dodge(gap=0.2))
```

[image: Plot using so]